# C++ for loop iteration changing integer vector values

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, vector

I am trying to solve a problem in which I need to store values in a vector and display the min and max values. **But** the min and max values I get by using *min_element and *max_element are **one more** than the actual values.

But when I use a for loop before it like this:

```cpp
for(int possibility: posibilities);
```

I get the actual values! Why is this happening? I am not doing anything inside the for loop and still it is the only thing that impacts the final output.

Using the input as:

```
3
2
3 6
3
1 3 5
5
1 2 5 6 7
```

Here is the output **with** and **without** the for loop:
[image: Outputs]

Here is my entire code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--){
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        int positions[n]; //Already sorted
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            cin >> positions[i];
        }

        int currentInfected = 1;
        vector<int> possibilities;

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for(int j = i; ((j <= n - i + 1) && (positions[j + 1] - positions[j] <= 2) ); j++){
                //Check Forward
                currentInfected++;
            }
            for(int j = i; ((j > 0) && (positions[j] - positions[j - 1] <= 2) ); j--){
                //Check Backward
                currentInfected++;
            }
            possibilities.push_back(currentInfected);
            currentInfected = 1; //Reset to one
        }

        //SOMEHOW THIS KEEPS THE VALUE IN THE VECTOR STEADY
        for(int possibility: possibilities);

        cout << *min_element(possibilities.begin(), possibilities.end()) << " " << *max_element(possibilities.begin(), possibilities.end()) << endl;


    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Compiler:** I am using the VS Code extension called **CompileRun**. Looking at it its docs, I think it uses mingw for windows and gcc for Linux.
[CompileRun Github](https://github.com/danielpinto8zz6/c-cpp-compile-run)

Comment: It is really unclear what you are actually trying to achieve. *store and access values from a vector* is not very much an explanation. Please explain in detail what you're trying to achieve. Also, please do not post your entire source code. Provide an [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead.

Comment: @Victor I am pushing values to a vector and want to display the min and max values in it

Comment: The preparation of a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is not just for our convenience; the bug is likely to become obvious to you in the process of simplifying the code. It is a vital coding skill.

Comment: @Beta Thanks for the info. It's my first question here and I tried my best :)

Comment: @Beta you can copy and paste my code and run it with and without the loop to reproduce the changes

Comment: @NeelanshMathur You can see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/HJZhT2) `std::min_element` and `std::max_element` are working properly (as we could have anticipated). So the problem is likely somewhere else in your code. Try to isolate the problem by eliminating different elements until you find the problematic one.

Comment: Yes, I could, and maybe I will if I have some free time later, but to find the bug I'd have to do a lot of work that *you could do.*

Comment: @Blastfurnace That is not a typo really. I used that instead of having a blank body, which gives the same output.

Comment: I see that now and deleted my comment. There's obviously some other problem in your code if that changes its behavior. Sorry I don't have an answer for you.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but `int positions[n]` is non-standard.

Comment: The [mre] is amazingly helpful. A very powerful debugging technique. The debugger that came with your development tools is an excellent aid to making the MRE, if not finding and solving the problem outright. Rewrite the code to automatically load an input set that invokes the error so you can easily keep attacking the same set. Then run the program in the debugger and step through the program line by line, keeping an eye on the variables and the paths the program takes. As soon as you see something unexpected, stop and investigate. It's probably a bug.

Comment: Also check your first `for(int j...)` loop. It seems you are accessing `positions` beyond the last element.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks, I will try that and edit the question :)

Comment: I change `positions` to be a `std::vector` and then changed all access from `[]` to `.at()` and your code throws a `std::out_of_range` exception. There's definitely an invalid index being used.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I will look into it. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Blastfurnace It....actually worked! Can't yet find out why the loop was behaving as such, but correcting the index solved the main problem :). You could post your answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  //SOMEHOW THIS KEEPS THE VALUE IN THE VECTOR STEADY
            for(int possibility: possibilities);

for debugging see what exactly you have in vector possibilities

for (int i = 0; i < possibilities.size(); i++) 
        cout << possibilities[i];

This will definitely print min and max value of vector possibilities:
            cout << *min_element(possibilities.begin(), possibilities.end()) << " " << *max_element(possibilities.begin(), possibilities.end()) << endl;

Comment: Actually, I discovered that the for loop alters the final values when I was printing the vector values! For posting it here, shortened it to just the blank loop.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all those who helped me. I can't say that I've arrived at an explanation, but I have figured out the problem.

The index issue as suggested by @Blastfurnace actually solved my main problem.

But I yet can't fathom why the iteration loop played a role in changing the output. I did narrow the bug down to the loop. It was the only thing that when added/removed, altered the output.
Thanks to everyone involved in this. This was my first question and I was overwhelmed by the response :)

Comment: Using an invalid index leads to undefined behavior. A program with undefined behavior isn't required to do anything reasonable. I just suggested some debugging advice to expose the real problem. I'm glad you found and fixed your bug.